# Spark UI Executors tab incorrect memory for --executor-memory

Tags: apache-spark

I am using spark 1.6 in YARN Client mode . Below is the spark-submit parameters

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --driver-memory 4G --executor-memory=6G --num-executors=5 --executor-cores=4
```

As you can see my driver memory is 4G in spark-submit command and my executor memory is 6G , but when i looked at the executors tab  in spark UI it shows as below . I want to know why it is happening . but in Environment tab it displays correct . Why storage memory is 3.1 GB instead of 6G. Actually i am expecting the executor memory to be more than 6G because of  executor memoryoverhead

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking at is storage memory. Spark will split the executor memory assigned for memoryOverhead, storage and execution.

memoryOverhead is calculated something like max(384, .07 * spark.executor.memory)

The remainder is split into storage (for cache/persist), execution and user memory. The default spark.memory.fraction is 0.6 (reserves 60% of memory assigned for storage and execution also known as spark memory; the rest is allocated to user memory)

```
MemoryOverhead: max(384, .07 * spark.executor.memory)
Spark Memory: (spark.executor.memory - memoryOverhead) * 0.6
User Memory: (spark.executor.memory - memoryOverhead) * 0.4
```

Comment: the `Storage Memory`  example  `2G/1G`  ,  what is the 2G mean?  It is the total usage since app start?  thank a lot

Comment: @roamer, it shows memory used / total available memory for storage of data